# Getting the number of columns and rows of a .csv file in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, csv

I am trying to write C++ code to input values from a .csv file to a matrix in C++. The .csv file contains floating point values and the size is usually >100x100.
I am unable to get the no. of rows and columns from the .csv file. They come from Matlab code which generates around 10 .csv file each of varying size. Hence I need to be able to get the size (in terms of rows and columns) of the .csv file automatically so that the 2D array can be delcared in C++ code.

The C++ code is:

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <iostream>

 /*const int ROWS = 2; 
 const int COLS = 7;*/
 const int BUFFSIZE = 80;

 int main()
 {
     char buff[BUFFSIZE];

     std::ifstream file("file.csv");
     std::string line;
     int col = 0;
     int row = 0;
     int a = 0, b = 0;

     while (std::getline(file, line))
     {
         std::istringstream iss(line);
         std::string result;
         while (std::getline(iss, result, ','))
         {
             col = col + 1;
             std::cout << col;
         }
         row = row + 1;
         std::cout << "\n";
         col = 0;
     }
     float array[row][col];


     while (std::getline(file, line))
     {
         std::istringstream iss(line);
         std::string result;
         while (std::getline(iss, result, ','))
         {
             array[a][b] = atof(result.c_str());
             b = b + 1;
         }
         a = a + 1;
         b = 0;
     }


     for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
         {
             std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
         }
         std::cout << "\n";
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

The output of the printing loops is just blank. The .csv file contains 2x7. How can I fix this? Is it because of the multiple usage of the `istringsteam()` and `getLine()`.
Kindly help. And note that I am a still a beginner at C++.

Comment: remove `col=0;` statement. Code counts the cols then sets cols to zero.

Comment: You can't use runtime variables as static array dimensions. You have to allocate dynamically or use a vector: `std::vector<std::vector<float>> array(row, std::vector<float>(col))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to move back the position of the stream before the second loop. After the last `while()` loop finished the stream reached the end. You now have to clear the error state and move back (you can also just close and reopen the file):

```c++
file.clear();
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

Moreover, you can't use runtime variables as static array dimensions. Your compiler uses a non-standard extension if it supports this. You have to allocate dynamically or use a vector:

```c++
std::vector<std::vector<float>> array(row, std::vector<float>(col))
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by using runtime variables as static array dimension. Could you elaborate? Also, I will implement the commands you suggested; and post the output.

Comment: The variables used to create an array should be either `const` or literals (meaning `5`, `10`, `23` etc.). Both of these qualities allows their values to be known at compile time. The C++ standard does not allow variable-length arrays (arrays with dimensions that are variables that are *not* `const`). Some compilers have extensions that allow you do this anyway, but they are not standard-conforming.

Comment: I made edits to the code, and have posted it. I however, am getting errors. Two with regards to the array declaration you suggested saying that the template argument is invalid. And 2 saying that array is not declared in the scope of the `main()`

Comment: @mysticsasuke Please don't make edits to the original question with updated code, it will only confuse new visiters to your question. You can post the updated code [here](http://ideone.com) and set me a link.

Comment: @mysticsasuke But right now I can already see that you made a mistake when creating the vector. You forgot the second closing `>` to the type.

Comment: Sorry. Will revert the changes made.

Comment: I think the errors I am getting may be caused by the version of C++ I am currently running. I think I have to install C++11. I currently have g++ version of 4.6.3. 
Here is the output from ideone : http://ideone.com/FHCGhf

Comment: prog.cpp:36:65: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 std::vector<std::vector<float>array(row, std::vector<float>(col));                                                                       
prog.cpp:36:65: error: template argument 2 is invalid                                                             

prog.cpp:47:9: error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope
         array[a][b] = atof( result.c_str() );
                                                                       
prog.cpp:63:16: error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope
     std::cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";

Comment: @mysticsasuke For the first error, you forgot the closing `>`. It should be `vector<vector<float>> array(...)`. As for the other errors, did you define `array` anywhere?

Comment: The code runs! The error it showed me after adding the `>` was that the command should be : `std::vector<std::vector<float> >array(row, std::vector<float>(col))` . Notice the space `> >`. However, when I print the array again using the `for` loops, there are zeroes at the end. Any particular reason for this?

Comment: @mysticsasuke Can you give me an [example](http://pastebin.com/) of your file please?

Comment: The code compiled fine. I think it was because of not setting `col=0` again in the first set of `while` loops. However, I am getting **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** when I execute the code now. 
The code is : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7245215/

Comment: @mysticsasuke Can you give me a example of the `.csv` file too? :)

Comment: Will try and post the result :). A couple of questions:
1) Does the C++ version matter a lot?
2) Which software/editor do you use to run C++? I am currently using g++ with the 'gedit' editor on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @mysticsasuke It matters in the sense that the C++ programming language is always improving with each new version. I always like to stay up to date with C++. The latest stable version is C++11 (and I can tell by your compiler errors that it doesn't support the latest version). I use g++ on Eclipse and sometimes on CodeBlocks. I also like to use the online editors.

Comment: No :(. It doesnt. It doesn't print all the numbers. Just the last followed by 7 zeroes, on each row. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Also, is there any way to input a bunch of .csv files of the format x_1.csv, x_2.csv ... and so on?? There are 36 files like that in total that need to be input to the C++ code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of commas in any row and that "count+1" will be the number of columns in your .csv file.

For number of rows you can simply write something like this -

```
int rows=0;
ifstream file("xyz.csv");
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
rows++;
```

Here "rows" will be the number of rows in your .csv file.

Check [this](https://github.com/abhinav1602/.csv-to-.cpp-2D-Array) repository if you need an example.